# How to include duplicate records in query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given an array of part ids containing duplicates, how can I find the corresponding records in my `Part` model, including the duplicates?

An example array of part ids would be `["1B", "4", "3421", "4"]`. If we assume I have a record corresponding to each of those values I would like to see 4 records returned in total, not 3. If possible, I was hoping to be able to make additional SQL operations on whatever is returned.

Here's what I'm currently using which doesn't include the duplicates:

```
@parts = Part.where(:part_id => params[:ids])
```

To give a little background, I'm trying to upload an XML file containing a list of parts used in some item. My application is meant to parse the XML file and compare the parts listed within against my Parts database so that I can see how much the part weighs. These items will sometimes contain duplicates of various parts so that's what I'm trying to account for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing it is using `map`...

```
@parts = params[:ids].map { |id| Part.find_by_id(id) }
```

Answer (score 0):

hard to tell exactly what you are doing, are you looking up weight from the xml or from your data?

```
parts_xml = some_method_that_loads_xml
part_ids_from_xml = part_xml.... # pull out the ids
parts = Part.where("id IN (?)", part_ids_from_xml)
```

now you have two arrays (xml data and your 'matching' database records) and you can use `select` or `detect` to do in memory lookups by part_id

```
part_ids_from_xml.each do |part_id| 
  weight = parts.detect { |item| item.id == part_id }.weight
  puts "#{id} weighs #{weight}"
end
```

see http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect

and http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select

Comment: Rails will do the `where IN` automatically, with `part_ids: ids`. You definitely don't have to manually build the `where in (?)` part.